# Is PRG On Concatenation of Input a PRG

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

This is a homework assignment, so I'm not expecting full solutions, just general guidance.

> Let a PRG $G:\left\{ 0,1\right\} ^{n}\to\left\{ 0,1\right\} ^{l\left(n\right)}$ (where $l\left(n\right)$ is a polynomial and
>   $l\left(n\right)>n$).
>
> Is $G':x\mapsto G\left(x\|x\right)$ a PRG? (where $\|$ is the concatenation operator).

My intuition (that is probably wrong) says it is not, since $\left|Im\left(G'\right)\right|\leq2^{n}$ whereas $\left|Im\left(U_{l\left(2n\right)}\right)\right|=2^{l\left(2n\right)}>2^{2n}$.

I'm not sure however how to show this.

I want to show a distinguisher between $U_{l\left(2n\right)}$ and $G'\left(U_{n}\right)$ with a non-negligible advantage, so I get input $z\in\left\{ 0,1\right\} ^{2n}$ and need to decide from which distribution it came from.

I thought about just checking whether $z\in Im\left(G'\right)$, but that can take $2^{n}$ to compute.

I would love some direction. Thanks!

Comment: If you seek to show that it is not a PRG in general, you do not need to find a generic attack on "any PRG of this form"; rather, you can come up with a specific construction that is a PRG, yet becomes clearly insecure when applied to $(x,x)$.

Comment: Excuse me if I'm wrong, I'm just a beginner in this field. I was under the impression we don't know whether a PRG exists, and that it's existence is equivalent to P!=NP problem.

Comment: Assume that PRGs actually exist (because the question becomes vacuous otherwise.) I.e. assume there is a PRG $G''$ for some convenient stretch. Use that to construct a PRG $G$, such that $G$ is secure but $G'$ is not.

Comment: What does convenient stretch mean? And obviously I assume G exists, but I can't make any assumptions on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured out the solution.

Assume such G exists (a PRG).

Then G' as described [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/40634/is-the-concatenation-of-prg-output-still-a-prg) is a PRG as well.

But applying it on $x\|x$ results in $G'':x\mapsto G\left(x\right)\circ G\left(x\right)$, which is not a PRG (easy to construct a distinguisher that checks if its input $z=z'\|z'$).

It is also possible to use $G′:\left(x\|y\right)↦x\|G\left(y\right)$ instead.

Comment: This is indeed a correct solution. Another approach (with a somewhat simpler reduction) would be $G' : (x\|y) \mapsto x\|G(y)$.